Python unittest how to mock function which external function is defined in __init__.py
I would like to test my_func2 that is calling my_func1. I would like to mock my_func1, but I don't know how can I do it when my_func2 is imported in my_package.__init__.py. When I delete that import, mock works correctly. But it is important to me to stay with that import in __init__.py. Please tell me how can I do it.
I have file structure as below:
├───my_package
│   │   my_func1.py
│   │   my_func2.py
│   │   __init__.py 
├───test
│   │   __init__.py
│   ├───test_my_package
│   │   │   test_my_func2.py
│   │   │   __init__.py

my_func1.py
def my_func1():
    return "I am my_func1"


my_func2.py
from my_package.my_func1 import my_func1


def my_func2():
    return my_func1()


init.py (in my_package)
from .my_func2 import my_func2

test_my_func2.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from my_package.my_func2 import my_func2


class TestMyFunc2(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("my_package.my_func2.my_func1")
    def test_my_func2(self, mock_my_func1):
        mock_my_func1.return_value = "MOCK DONE"
        result = my_func2()
        print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()


I have tried different combinations with @patch paths. Nothing helped. The only solution I have already found is to delete import from my_package.__init__.py but I am not allowed to do it.

Having a module with the same name as a function in that module exposed by your package is probably a bad idea. If you actually need a separate submodule, give it a  separate,  module-like name (my_module2), or define my_func2 directly in __init__.py.

Thank you. I resolved the issue by changing the my_func2 function name. However, if anyone knows how to fix this without changing function or file names, I would be grateful for the advice.
